# Table Creation Results into ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table, but I keep getting this error:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE salesreport 
(
    pid number(10) NOT NULL,
    uid number(10) NOT NULL,
    pname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    price number(10) NOT NULL,
    qty number(10) NOT NULL,
    dateoforder varchar2(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    total varchar2(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX pid ON salesreport (pid, uid);
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: i tried but still same error

Comment: You should make `dateoforder` a date type, _not_ text.

Answer (score 3):

`uid` is a reserved word. Pick something else and it should work.

OR write it like this

```
CREATE TABLE salesreport (
   pid number(10) NOT NULL,
  "uid" number(10) NOT NULL,
  pname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  price number(10) NOT NULL,
  qty number(10) NOT NULL,
  dateoforder date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  total varchar2(30) NOT NULL
);

INDEX pid ON salesreport (pid,"uid");
```

Comment: i tried this now its giving this error "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Comment: What are you using to create the table? Tool wise

Comment: Use this: `dateoforder date DEFAULT SYSDATE`

Comment: im using oracle 10g @jucan

Comment: thanks i solved this query with help of you guzz. solution is: CREATE TABLE salesreport (
  pid number(10) NOT NULL,
  "uid" number(10) NOT NULL,
  pname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  price number(10) NOT NULL,
  qty number(10) NOT NULL,
 dateoforder date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  total varchar2(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX pid ON salesreport (pid,"uid");

Comment: It would be wise to mark the question answered if it helped solve your issue.